# C#: convert IntPtr to array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, intptr

I don't know much about pointers when it comes to C#. I'm writing some code that accesses functions/classes in an external 3rd party library (the .NET extension of 3dsmax).

One function in the API takes a pointer to an array of objects and assigns color values to those objects, from pixels in a bitmap. The objects themselves have 4 properties -> a float for each RGBA value of a color...so their class is essentially layed out like this:

```
public class IBMM_Color_fl: IEquatable<IBMM_Color_fl>, IDisposable, INativeObject
{
    public float R; 
    public float G; 
    public float B; 
    public float A;
}
```

I initialize my pointer with:

```
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float)*4*numberOfPixels);
```

And then pass it to the API, and the API does its work on the pointer without generating any errors. After the function completes, I want to convert the pointer to an array to get the pixel color values, but don't know how. I tried Marshal.PtrToStructure but I get the error:

```
The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information
```

When I searched for answers regarding this error I read that there are ways to modify your class to be blit-friendly, but the class is initialized in the 3rd party's DLLs and so I have no way to modify its properties. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` if you really it to be a `class`. Not seeing the point of `IDisposable`, so it can be a `struct` and you should be done.

Comment: The class is not written by me, it's contained in the 3rd party's DLLs...so I can't change it.

Comment: Something seems very wrong then. Show the signature of the method you calling with `IBMM_Color_fl`

Comment: What is `INativeObject`? That seems like it could be related to what you're trying to do. As a workaround you may be able to make a `struct` that is equivalent to that class, use it for communication with the unmanaged code, then translate it to the class.

Comment: "As a workaround you may be able to make a struct that is equivalent to that class, use it for communication with the unmanaged code, then translate it to the class. " Thank you, that was the key to get it working. I guess the classes that were being inherited had members that the marshal didn't like.